# Should delimited text file have a delimiter after the final column?

Tags: ssis, csv

Should a delimited text file contain the delimiter to the right of the last column?
Imagine a pipe-delimited file intended to contain 3 columns:  Column1, Column2, Column3.

Which is "correct", or which would you expect?

Column1|Column2|Column3|

Value1|Value2|Value3|

**Or**

Column1|Column2|Column3

Value1|Value2|Value3

(sorry about the extra line space in between - stack overflow refuses to recognize my line break - wtf).
I'm trying to get SSIS to recognize a file to source a flat file connection and there are supposed to be 39 columns.  The person provided me a file without a delimiter after the last column's value.  SSIS does not recognize it right UNTIL i add the pipe symbol AFTER the last column value - but maybe there is some other factor or reason?

Comment: The second one is what I would expect as the delimiter provides a separation between two entities. The trailing delimiter is not required as the carriage return/line feed/carriage return + line feed is generally used as the row delimiter. I would only expect scenario 1 in the event that the file is presented exactly as `Column1|Column2|Column3|Value1|Value2|Value3|` (no line breaks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your flat file connection properties are wrong and EOL is not correctly recognized.

In `Flat File Connection manager Editor` go in `Advanced` tab. You should find a number of column (39 as you stated). Each one should have the same `ColumnDelimiter` except the last one than in a case like `Column1|Column2|Column3` (that is the most common) should be something like `{CR}{LF}`

Try with different delimiter, maybe the file has a different return carriage than the one you expect (anyway should be one betwwen `{CR}{LF}`, `{CR}`, `{LF}`)

[image]

Comment: Your answer prompted me to check for the carriage return character (which I had not really checked whether it was present).  Sure enough, it was not present.  I will go back to the user to inform them that all data lines must terminate with a ascii decimal 10 or 13.  Thanks!